# PHP form shell_exec output

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to do a small project (for personal use) and I am a little stuck with a particular part of this.

I have the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>

        <form action="" method=post>
        <input type="text" name="ipaddress"/>
        <input name="submit" type=submit value="Command">
        </form>

        <?php
            if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
                $ipaddress = $_REQUEST['ipaddress'];
                $output = shell_exec("ping -c 5 $ipaddress");
                echo "<pre>$output</pre>\n";
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is basically a test box in a form where a user can enter an IP address. This does work, and outputs the results on the page. What I'm trying to achieve is a live output of the response coming through as if this was being run from the CLI (essentially a line by line return of the output).

I have looked at various methods, including SSE but unfortunately, I've been unable to achieve this.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction or let me know where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe PHP is running in safe mode?

Comment: Additionally I guess you mean `ping -n 5 $ipaddress`!

Comment: can you `var_dump($ipaddress)` and see any output?

Comment: @Ben, I can see the output, but only after the ping has finished. Not whilst it's running like http://ping.eu/ping/

Comment: add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and see any error / warning output.